# Getting a List of File Names from a table field using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listbox, getfiles

I have a Combox1 Bound to a SQL Dataset using a GroupName and also contained in the dataset is a ImportPath field.

I want to be able to grab the ImportPath field value and then use it to populate a list box with a list of *.csv files from that ImportPath folder.

I need help with the syntax to initialize the curFileNames() variable - the error I get is saying

> Value of type 'DataColumn' cannot be converted to 'String'

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim curSelectionCombobox = DataSet1.Fulfillment_Only_Groups.ImportPathColumn

    **Dim curFileNames() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(curSelectionCombobox, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.csv")**

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how it's being bound?

Comment: If the `ComboBox.DisplayMember` is set to "GroupName", simply set the `ValueMember` to "ImportPathColumn". Then under the `SelectedValue` changed event, do ` curSelectionCombobox = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The line where you get the error is `DataSet1.Tables(0).Columns(0)`. It, of course, returns a `DataColumn`. I think want you want is the value of that column.

You also completely garbled the `.GetFiles` function.

I would be much easier to do as @preciousbetine suggested in comments but if you don't want to change `ComboBox1` then do this.

```
Dim dt = DataSet1.Tables("Fulfillment_Only_Groupg")
Dim curSelectionCombobox = (From r As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
                            Where r("GroupName").ToString = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
                            Select r("ImportPathColumn")).FirstOrDefault.ToString
Dim curFileNames() = Directory.GetFiles(curSelectionCombobox, "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all your help, it helped lead me to a suitable solution: here is the code that works when my Combobox and Textbox change. I had to put the code in the Textbox_Textchanged Sub to get it to refresh correctly. It is bound like the Combobox to my DataSet so changes automatically when a Select a new option from the Comboxbox.

Private Sub txtImportFolder_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtImportFolder.TextChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        If ComboBox1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then

```
        Dim curSelectionCombobox = txtImportFolder.Text.ToString
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(curSelectionCombobox) Then
            For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(curSelectionCombobox)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(file)
            Next
        End If
    End If
    ListBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```